# how can I do html table left column and header fixed?

Tags: html

how can I do html table left column and header fixed ?
I received this reference

```
http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/7/
```

I just want content scrolling
thank you

```
https://jsfiddle.net/Anatolium/DJqPf/1239/
```

I tried this but it did not

```
  .header th {
      position: fixed;
    left: 5px
}

https://jsfiddle.net/Anatolium/DJqPf/1243/
```

and I want to make a single table

I saw this example but I can not use... because my project only for  single dynamic table

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/GnN66/2/
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did what you want exactly see the below css code & more info click the following js fiddle link

```
.header{float:left;width:100%;background:#fff;height:60px;}
.header tr{position:fixed;background:#fff;}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vetri/ksdgq3ea/)

Comment: hello yes it is.. vel thank you for reply but How would header left move ? content and header simultaneously move to left and upper  http://i.hizliresim.com/07a1ZY.png I hope you understand me my english is not good